# DQL getResult return array

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm playing with Doctrine, and I think I probably miss something.
So I have a table for some relations, and here is the columns:

id | user_id | workshop_id

Basically, I use this table to know that a user is register for a workshop.

I want to **count** how many users subscribe for a workshop.

So in my Repository, I use a DQL request:

```php
/** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

$query = $entityManager->createQuery("
    SELECT COUNT('uw.id')
    FROM App\Entity\UserWorkshops AS uw
    LEFT JOIN App\Entity\User AS u WITH u.userId = uw.user
    WHERE uw.workshop = :workshop_id");

$count = $query
    ->setParameters(['workshop_id' => $workshopId])
    ->getResult();
```

And here, and example of the result:
[image]

I just need to retrieve 3, as an integer.

How can I return something different ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getSingleScalarResult, from the doc[:](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats)

> Query#getSingleScalarResult(): Retrieves a single scalar value from
>   the result returned by the dbms. If the result contains more than a
>   single scalar value, an exception is thrown. The pure/mixed
>   distinction does not apply.

As example:

```
$count = $query
    ->setParameters(['workshop_id' => $workshopId])
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: yes, I get lost in the documentation and I did not see this one.
Thanks for your help!